# How to make Composite Primary Key Using Two Foreign key?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have Three table  in which one table is using the foreign key of other two table to make the composite primary key.   Now i am using the  @Embeddable  but as both the key are the  foreign key, How  i will create the composite primary key now in the Entity.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(table1id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (table1id));
```

table2

```
CREATE TABLE table2
(table2id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (table2id));
```

table3

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
   table1id INT NOT NULL,
   table2id INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (table1id, table2id),
   FOREIGN KEY (table1id) REFERENCES table1 (table1id),
   FOREIGN KEY (table2id) REFERENCES table2 (table2id)
);
```

How to convert this table into an Hibenate Entity.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="table3")
 class Table1 {
   @Id
   long table1id;
   //getter and setter
  }

 @Entity
 @Table(name="table3")
   class Table2 {
   @Id
   long table2id;
   //getter and Setter
   }

  @Entity
  @Table(name="table3")
  class Table3 {
     @EmbeddedId
     private table3PK table3PKId;

   //getter and Setter
   }


 @Embeddable
  Class table3PK{

  @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="table1Id" ,referencedColumnName="table1id")
  Table1 table1;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="table2Id" ,referencedColumnName="table2id")
  Table2 table2;

  public table3PK(){

  }

  public table3PK(Table1 table1 ,Table2 table2){
   this.table1;
   this.table2;
  }


 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what problem you are encountering; but you might try using "derived identities" and mapping your entities like this:

```
@Entity
public class Table1 {
    @Id
    long table1id;
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Table2 {
    @Id
    long table2id;
    // ...
}

@Embeddable
public class Table3PK {
    long table1PK; // corresponds to PK type of Table1
    long table2PK; // corresponds to PK type of Table2
} 

@Entity
public class Table3 {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Table3PK id;

    @MapsId("table1PK") // maps table1PK attribute of embedded id 
    @ManyToOne
    Table1 table1;

    @MapsId("table2PK") // maps table2PK attribute of embedded id 
    @ManyToOne
    Table2 table2;

    // ...
}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. It is very helpful. But I have a issue when I try to persist this `Table3` entity. It says `Could not set field value [15] value by reflection....`. Can you please help me to fix this